# Mapping value from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, mapping

I have dataframe a:

```
    TagID   Genre
0   0       rock
1   1       pop
2   2       favorites
3   3       alternative
4   4       love
```

and dataframe b:

```
    Tags
0   154
1   20 35 40 65
```

I want the result like this:

```
  Genre
0 wjlb-fm
1 chill, rnb, loved, hip hop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode your `Tags` column before joining to first dataframe:

```
df2['Genre'] = (df2['Tags'].str.split().explode().astype(df1['TagID'].dtype)
                           .map(df1.set_index('TagID')['Genre'])
                           .groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join))
print(df2)

# Output
    Tags                 Genre
0      3           alternative
1  1 4 2  pop, love, favorites
```

Step by step:

```
# 1. Explode your column
>>> out = df2['Tags'].str.split().explode().astype(df1['TagID'].dtype)
0    3
1    1
1    4
1    2
Name: Tags, dtype: int64

# 2. Match genre by tag id
>>> out = out.map(df1.set_index('TagID')['Genre'])
0    alternative
1            pop
1           love
1      favorites
Name: Tags, dtype: object

# 3. Reshape your dataframe
>>> out = out.groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
0             alternative
1    pop, love, favorites
Name: Tags, dtype: object
```

Comment: @DilaAzuri - Performance is not important? What is size of DataFrame?

Answer (score 1):

You can create dictionary by `TagID` and `Genre` and then in generator split values by space with mapping numbers converted to dict:

```
print (df2)
      Tags
0        1
1  2 3 4 5

d = df1.set_index('TagID')['Genre'].to_dict()
f = lambda x: ' '.join(d[int(y)] for y in x.split() if int(y) in d)
df2['Genre'] = df2['Tags'].apply(f)
print (df2)
      Tags                       Genre
0        1                         pop
1  2 3 4 5  favorites alternative love
```